# React.js return a style property from a function and use it inside the render() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to use a dynamic style property. The approach below throws me an "The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string" error.

```
class someClass extends React.Component {
    someFunction = () => {
        return {marginLeft : 20 };
    }
    render() {
        return( <div style={this.someFunction}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Howerver this one works:

```
class someClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return( <div style={{marginLeft : 20}}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Why is that so and how can i return style objects from functions?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't call the function inside the style props JSX. Call it like `this.someFunction()`, then it will return the object of style you kept inside the `someFunction`.

```
return <div style={this.someFunction()} />
```